# I keep getting this "Syntax error on token "(", ; expected after this token" error?

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax

```
package mathtable;

public class tablefmath {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final int jMax = 10;
    final int iMax = 15;
    int column=1, row=1;

    System.out.println(" " + "  |  ");

    for (column<=jMax; column++) {
        System.out.println(column + "\t");
    }           
}
}
```

This is my code. I want to accomplish a multiplication table. I know how to do it but I have a syntax error on my for loop?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
for (; column<=jMax; column++){
```

You skipped the `;` in the for loop. It should be containing three components.

Comment: well it partially worked. I need to to look like this: 1    2    3    4   5... so on but it just skips lines